# run different versions of code at the same time

Tags: c++, git, workflow

I am currently writing a chess engine in c++. I use github for version control. When I make changes to the engine, I need to test it against the older version to see if it has improved. This is the part I am having trouble with. Until now, I have kept different versions of the engine in different files, and then imported these files in a `compare_playing_strength.cpp` file to make them play against each other. However, this is code duplication, and it is hard to keep everything compatible. I am sure there is a better way to do this.

I feel like my question is very general, but I haven't found any ways to solve it. I thought about using different git branches for different versions, but then I can't test the engines against each other. Am I thinking about this the wrong way, or is there a way to make this work?

Comment: How do you measure improvements? Can the test-program automatically detect it or measure the statistics needed somehow? Can it then be written to text-files that can be compared? Then you only need the current version of the code, but have to keep the text-files for each version.

Comment: Consider [tag:git-worktree].

Comment: You do need *some* kind of stable API (UCI?) to make it not hard to keep everything compatible. After that, you can check out tags (or branches, sure, if you keep developing old versions) and build them into different directories.

Comment: If you can't measure or get statistics from your test-program, just checkout multiple versions in multiple (independent) directories and build as separate projects. Then run the two test-programs simultaneously and do the manual testing you need.

Comment: `git checkout old-commit` `build old version` `git checkout main` `build new version`

Comment: @some_programmer_dude There are multiple ways to measure the performance, for instance there is no problem when I measure the time to reach a certain depth of search. But what i would like to do is make the two versions play complete chess games against each other, so i can measure their relative elo. To do this i really need the two versions at the same time.

Comment: @ted_Lyngmo I am new to git so i am not sure to understand how the branches communicate?

Comment: Do you have more than one branch?

Comment: I have the main engine, and modified versions i am working on. If these play better than the main engine, I would like to update the main code. So I should make a branch for each modified version?

Comment: In principle -- there are some technicalities to work out, but in principle -- would you be able to use something like a second build target to compile your engine into a library? Then your process would be check out the old version, build the library, check out the new version, then build the executable linked against the library.

Comment: Do both engines have to live in the same executable? Would you be interested in designing (or finding) an interface so that your chess program can communicate with another, allowing the two programs to play each other? (The second program would not need to be one of yours.) If you did this, you could easily have your new engine play an old one -- or even against someone else's engine, if both engines agree on the communication protocol.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes! Currently, the engines live in the same executable. So maybe I can implement the UCI protocol, and modify `compare_playing_strength.cpp to make it run different executables. Even though i am not sure how to achieve this (as i am a beginner), this seems to be a good solution combined with @VonC's answer. Thank you very much for your insight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use separate branches for each version of your chess engine.
For instance, have a `main` branch for the current development and create branches like `version1`, `version2`, etc., for older versions.

Make sure your repository is structured such that it is easy to compile and run different versions.
For example, you might have a directory structure like this:

```
chess_engine/
├── src/
├── include/
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── compare_playing_strength.cpp
```

[`git worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-worktree) (that I [presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)) can be useful in your scenario. It allows you to check out and work with multiple branches of the same repository simultaneously in separate directories.

Your main repository rests on the `main` branch, where you do your current development.

For each version of your chess engine that you want to test, you create a new worktree. This allows you to have a separate working directory for each version, all linked to the same repository.

For example, to create a worktree for `version1`:

```bash
git worktree add ../engine-version1 version1
```

This command will create a new directory `../engine-version1` where the `version1` branch is checked out.

Each worktree operates independently. You can make changes, compile, and run tests in one worktree without affecting others.

Use your `compare_playing_strength.cpp` to make different versions play against each other. Since each version is in a separate directory, you can easily compile and run them independently.

---

As suggested by [JaMiT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9837301/jamit) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77816819/run-different-versions-of-code-at-the-same-time?noredirect=1#comment137185774_77816819), implementing the [Universal Chess Interface (UCI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Chess_Interface) protocol in your chess engines would allow different versions of your chess engine, or even entirely different engines, to communicate and play against each other.

You can modify both the old and new versions of your chess engines to implement the UCI protocol. It will allow your engines to receive commands (like making a move) and send responses in a standardized format.

Compile each version of your engine as a separate executable. That means you will have an executable for each significant version of your engine (e.g., `engine_v1.exe`, `engine_v2.exe`, etc.).

Adjust your `compare_playing_strength.cpp` to launch and manage two separate engine processes (the two executables). Implement logic to send UCI commands to these engines, receive their responses, and handle game logic (like maintaining the board state and enforcing rules).

When you want to compare two versions, run `compare_playing_strength.cpp`, which will in turn run the two engine executables. The `compare_playing_strength.cpp` program will act as the controller, sending commands to both engines and managing the game flow.

That means you can test any two versions of your engine against each other, or even test your engine against third-party UCI-compliant engines. Each engine runs in its own process, which reduces complexity and potential interference.

Answer (score 2):

This problem arises when the testing/benchmarking code is in the same repo with the business logic. This is a general software engineering problem and there are several ways to solve it, each with their nuances.

- If you want to keep both in the same repo then it is better to split the different algorithms in separate files. Factor out the common code in common files. This works great when for testing multiple strategies.
- If you are testing improvements over small changes like tuning parameters. Then it is better to parameterize the tunable parameters and take those parameters as input from a file.
- You could also move the benchmarking code in a separate repository and that will allow testing arbitrary changes to your current repository. This is typically useful for large projects IMO.